# getstaticprops nextjs fetch all page at first time

Tags: next.js

500 brothers. why nextjs fetch all json files at the first time I land on the page. I am used getstaticprops for those pages. I am afraid that will affect the performance.i expect that the json just should be fetched when I land on that page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FS0y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `Link` and by default, `Link` has `prefetch={true}` which means your page will prefetch all your data from all other pages' links. You can check [this doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link).

These prefetching behaviors run in the background, so you don't need to worry about performance.

If you are still concerned about it, you can set `Link` like below

```
<Link prefetch={false} href={...}>
   <a>...</a>
</Link>
```

*Side note that whenever you hover on `Link`, it will start prefetching, although you set `prefetch={false}`.*